# UNION ALL with where clause in mysql

Tags: mysql, union

I have two `select` statements in mysql.

I need to `union` the two mysql queries with `where` clause in common for two `select` statements.
Any ideas?

EX:

```
(SELECT leases.id,leases.commencement as term, leases.commencement as start_date, leases.execution as execution
FROM `leases` leases.commencement > CURDATE())a
UNION ALL
(SELECT leases.id, leases.commencement as term, leases.commencement as start_date, leases.execution as execution
FROM `leases` leases.commencement BETWEEN '2014/01/01' and CURDATE()) b 
where a.commencement=b.commencement
```

Comment: post the queries and what needs to be used in where clause.

Comment: What are you tried so far?

Comment: You appear to be mixing up the idea of a UNION (add result of one query onto the result of another), with a JOIN (matching the rows of one set of rows with another set of rows). Also as you first query gets all rows where commencement is in the future and the 2nd gets all those in the (recent) past, and you appear to want to match on the commencement date they are mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you are trying to do a `UNION`. rather you are trying to do a `JOIN` between two derived tables like below

```
SELECT a.*,b.*
FROM
(
SELECT leases.id,
leases.commencement as term,
leases.commencement as start_date,
leases.execution as execution
FROM leases 
WHERE leases.commencement > CURDATE()
) a
JOIN
(
SELECT leases.id as ID1,
leases.commencement as term1,
leases.commencement as start_date1,
leases.execution as execution1
FROM leases 
WHERE leases.commencement 
BETWEEN '2014/01/01' and CURDATE()
)b ON a.commencement=b.commencement
```